# Singleton in ASP.NET Core allows multiple instances

Tags: asp.net-core, dependency-injection, singleton

I have implemented very simple code to check functionality of dependency injection in ASP.NET Core 2.1.

Unfortunately, I got others results as I expected. Every time, when I refresh site, I got another id instead the same.

Startup.cs

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{    
    services.AddMvc();
    services.AddSingleton<IPerson, Person>();
}
```

HomeController.cs

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private IPerson _person;

    public HomeController( IPerson person)
    {
        _person = person;
    }

    public ViewResult Index()
    {
        return View( "Index", $"{_person.id}");
    }
}
```

Person.cs

```
public interface IPerson
{
    string id { get; }
}

public class Person : IPerson
{
    public string id => Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
}
```

I suspect, the reason is very simply, but really don't understand what I made wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the problem is how you've defined the `Id` property on your `Person` class:

```cs
public class Person : IPerson
{
    public string id => Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
}
```

This means: every time the code asks for the `id` - it gets a **newly created** Guid - so **of course** you keep getting new/different Guid's every time you look at your person!

You need to get the `id` **once** - in the `Person` constructor - and then return that:

```cs
public class Person : IPerson
{
    private string _id;

    public void Person()
    {
        _id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
    }

    public string id => _id;
}
```

I'm **pretty sure** once you've done this, the singleton will work - you keep getting back the same instance of `Person` every time you look at it.

Answer (score 2):

`Person.id` is a property defined with as expression-bodied property that returns a new Guid everytime it's called, so even though it might be the same instance, calling `Person.id` will get you a new value every time.

To properly test it define the class as:

```
public class Person : IPerson
{
  private string id;

  public Person()
  {
    this.id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
  }

  public string Id => this.id;
}
```

Now `id` field will be initialized upon class creation and the `Id` property should return the same value for each request.